# How to give access inside Groovy script to a field by adding getter for a field through an annotation

Tags: java, reflection, groovy

I have a model class with fields inside:

```
public class Model1 {
  @Bind private int LL; 
  @Bind private  double[] twKI; 
  @Bind private  double[] twKS; 
  @Bind private  double[] twINW; 
  @Bind private  double[] twEKS; 
}
```

I created an annotation:

```
import java.lang.annotation.ElementType;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;

@Target(ElementType.FIELD)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME) 

public @interface Bind {


}
```

Is it possible to define getter and setters for fields inside `Model1` class without modyfing it so later on they will by available in groovy script?

Comment: Do you want to auto-create getters setters via annotation processing (build time;see [Project Lombok](https://projectlombok.org/)) or auto-create getters and setters at run time?

Comment: @mlk I try to get to modify these fields via reflection like(simplified example): `modelClass.getDeclaredField("LL").set(model, 10);` but I get `java.lang.IllegalAccessException: Class zad1.Controller can not access a member of class zad1.models.Model1 with modifiers "private"` and the teacher forgave to modify the `Model1` class so I look for a way to define getters for a field outside the class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well you have multiple choices and you can choose whichever suits you better:

We have a model object: `Model model = new Model()`

**1. Using getter and setters**:
    Create getters and setter methods and then call the setter method: `model.setLL(10)`

**2. Without getter and setters**:
    Well in groovy/grails scope variables doesn't make much difference until you are overriding them for some specific purpose. So you can directly set the value using `model.LL = 10`

**3. Using setProperty**: `model.setProperty('LL', 10)`

**4. Reflection way**: before setting the field value, mark it as accessible.

```
Field field = Model.getDeclaredField("LL")
field.setAccessible(true)
field.set(model, 10)
```

Comment: I checked the 4th way and it already throws an exception at `Field field = model.getDeclaredField("LL")`-> `Class Controller can not access a member of class zad1.models.Model1 with modifiers "private"`

Comment: This exception gets thrown when you try to set value, not when you try to get the field. And after marking it as accessible, you won't get this exception. I have verified it myself.

Comment: I know that this is what should happenn and it is shown in some tutorials. For some reason I get exception in the place I've told you.

Comment: After I reopenned all the files the exception stopped beign thrown. Of course I was saving all files before. It must've been Eclipse bug.